# How display model with four relationships based on date in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, datatable

I have these models:

- Partner
- Invoice
- Bill
- Transaction
- CreditNote

Invoice, Bill, Transaction, and CreditNote belong to Partner.

and Partner has many invoices, bills, transactions, credit_notes.

I want to make SOA reports, which are based on date.

for example:

```
DATE      TYPE                   ITEM
2021-1-1  partner invoiced us   invoice_number..
2021-1-2  us invoiced partner   bill_number..
2021-1-3  partner paid us       transaction_debit
2021-1-4  us paid partner       transaction_credit
2021-1-5  partner paid us       credit_note
```

I use `rappasoft livewire data table to show this information.

I get partner stuff like this:

```
Partner::where('id', 1)->with('invoices', 'bills', 'transactions', 'credit_notes')->get()
```

I don't know how to display these information in a table a sort based on date

How to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? If the relationships always need to be ordered by date , you can add a `orderBy()` where you define the relationship in your model.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like your structure is wrong. All of the five things that you're putting in your table are what I'd consider "transactions" (not to be confused with your model "Transactions".

That being the case, then you want either want a Transactions model which is morphable (that's the more complicated solution) or which has a "type" property.

If morphable, each transaction would then be associated to the corresponding partner, and to the corresponding model - invoice, bill, payment, refund, etc. - on a "morphsTo" basis.

If you went down the easier route, each transaction would just have a type, linked to a TransactionType model, which would indicate the type of the transaction.

As things stand, your structure is overcomplicated. Either of the above approaches would simplify it.